# Trying to pass Boolean value from child component to parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

**Child Component:**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './app-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  testBoolean: boolean;

  constructor() { }
}
```

**Parent Component**

**.html**

```
<app-test [testBoolean]="testBoolean"></app-test>
<button (click)="onClick()"></button>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test1',
  templateUrl: 'app-test1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app-test1.component.scss']
})
export class TestParentComponent {

  @Input() testBoolean;

  constructor() { }

  onClick() {
    console.log(this.testBoolean);
  }
}
```

When I run the application getting below error:

Can't bind to 'testBoolean' since it isn't a known property of 'app-test'.

1. If 'app-test' is an Angular component and it has 'testBoolean' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-test' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

Comment: Mark the `testBoolean` in the child component as `@Input()`. Without it, angular can't bind the boolean value to the child's field.

Answer (score 0):

Dan is right,

```
import { Component,Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './app-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() testBoolean: boolean;

  constructor() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wrong but you mean to ask you are getting error in passing data from parent to child which as rightly said in answer need to use @Input() property .
If you want to pass data from child component to parent there are multiple ways one way is to use output property in child component
@Output() someEvent = new EventEmitter();

and on click of child component pass some data using emit

```
click() {
       this.someEvent.emit({isChild: true});
}
```

Now in parent component listen inside app-test using

```
<app-test (someEvent)="onClickEventCLicked($event)" >
```

in parent component's ts file you can access value inside
onClickEventClicked function
as

```
 onClickEventClicked(value: {test: boolean}) {
  console.log(value);
}
```